# Add a button to close notification in android 4.1+ without creating a new activity

Tags: android, notifications, android-activity

I want to add a button to my notification to close it, since it's persistent. I have 2 button. One of them I use addAction, because I call another activity. But the other just need to close the notification. The only way I found is to create a new Activity with the action to close the notification, so I could do the close button the same thing I did with the other button.

But is there a way to do this withou creating a new activity?

I don't know if it's clear enough, if you can't understand please tell me and I try to explain better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to use the notification manager

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```